# webHttpBinding having issue with posting 1MB xml file

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, visual-studio

I have webHttpBinding for wcf service. Can not post large xml file (1MB) to service getting following error RequestEntityTooLarge (413) is not one of the following: OK (200), Created (201), Accepted (202), NonAuthoritativeInformation (203), NoContent (204), ResetContent (205), PartialContent (206)"}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

Here is configuration for wcf service..

```
<service name="abc" >
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8741/LTLInboundService/" binding="webHttpBinding"                  behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour" contract="abc" name="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService" >
        </endpoint>
</service>

   <webHttpBinding>
       <binding name="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
        openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        transferMode="Streamed" 
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
       <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
       </security>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
```

Here is the code that is failing..

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient("http://localhost:8741/LTLInboundService" + "/SendCompletionReports"))
{
    // Initalise a response object
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    string responseFilePath = Path.Combine(@"c:\Samir\abc.xml");
    string xmlData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(responseFilePath);

    // Create a content object for the request
    HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create(xmlData, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

    // Make the request and retrieve the response
    response = client.Post("http://localhost:8741/LTLInboundService" + "/SendCompletionReports", content);

    // Throw an exception if the response is not a 200 level response
    response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();

    // Retrieve the content of the response for processing
    response.Content.LoadIntoBuffer();
}
```

It fails on `response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();` statement.

Any idea how to fix this in development and production ?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this site and pay attention to how they have this section configured under the security section 
[Dealing with Larger Files in Asp.NET](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I have multiple services created under same wcf project and they all starts in Global.asax.cs file dynamically.. Please help.. thanks

Comment: perhaps you should show the code that you have in your .asax.cs file

Comment: checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380352/httpclient-failing-in-accessing-simple-website 
look at `adriano-repetti` answer are you familiar with Proxy's

Comment: that post is related to proxy server authentication with error code 407.. i am getting RequestEntityTooLarge error code (413).. it is big file which is failing smaller files working fine :(

Comment: is there a way that you can Stream the large file by doing Buffer Chuncks ? perhaps

Comment: May be not sure, i am new to WCF trying to find best possible solution to fix this issue.. it is just 1MB file and per documentation it should support upto 2 GB.. what configuration might be missing.. :(

Comment: try this codeproject solution you can experiment with changing the buffer size looks like this might help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `webHttpBinding` in your config file, but it's not being used by your service because you did not specify it in the `bindingConfiguration` attribute.

```
<service name="abc" >
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8741/LTLInboundService/"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour" contract="abc" 
            name="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService" >
  </endpoint>
</service>
```

The `name` attribute is used for the endpoint configuration, but has no bearing on the binding configuration used.  In your `<endpoint>` element add this:

```
bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService"
```

so your defined endpoint will use the values for the binding specified, not the default.

Final endpoint would look like this:

```
<service name="abc" >
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8741/LTLInboundService/"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService"
            behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour" contract="abc" 
            name="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService" >
  </endpoint>
</service>
```

Comment: I did that and now getting following error.. in service start up..An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https

Comment: Your defined binding has security mode set to transport - either use `https` or set the security mode to None.